# Convert GMT DateTime String

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, gmt

I am pretty new to Java and I am a little stuck with using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. I have a Date-Object and want to extract a GMT datestring like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. I live in Germany and at the moment we are GMT +0200. My Date-Object's time is for example `2011-07-18 13:00:00`. What I need now is `2011-07-18 11:00:00`. The offset for my timezone should be calculated automatically.

I tried something like this, but I guess there is a fault somewhere:

```
private String toGmtString(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(new SimpleTimeZone(timeZone.getOffset(date.getTime()), "GMT"));
    sd.setCalendar(cal);
    return sd.format(date);
}
```

On some devices the datestring is returned like I want it to. On other devices the offset isn't calculated right and I receive the date and time from the input date-object. Can you give me some tips or advices? I guess my way off getting the default timezone does not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private String toGmtString(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return sd.format(date);
}
```

You don't need to create a new `SimpleTimeZone`, because you aren't inventing a new timezone - there are 2 existing timezones that come into play in your program, GMT and your default one.

You also don't need to modify your existing date object, because you don't want to represent a different point in time - you only want a different way to display the same point in time.

All you need to do is tell the `SimpleDateFormat` which timezone to use in formatting.

Comment: I can't believe that it is that easy, but of course I will try that too. Give me some minutes please...

Comment: Ok.. Tested.. I used a date-object which represents `2011-07-18 13:34:27`. Using the default date function `.toGMTString()` I receive `18 Jul 2011 11:43:27 GMT` which is the exact point in time that I need.Using my own function I still receive `2011-07-18 13:43:27` which was my problem. Using Jigar Joshin's function I receive `2011-07-18 12:43:27` which is missing 1 hour (european summertime). Using Eli Acherkans function I receive `2011-07-18 11:43:27` which is exactly what I wanted to (Offset including european summertime).

Comment: You're a live saver @EliAcherkan!

Answer (score 2):

```
private String toGmtString(Date date){
    //date formatter
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    //getting default timeZone
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    //getting current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(date) ;
    //adding / substracting curren't timezone's offset
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1 * timeZone.getRawOffset());    
    //formatting and returning string of date
    return sd.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Ok this is looking good. I will give it a try in a few minutes. One question. Where and how did you use the date-parameter from the function call?! Should I use `cal.setTime(date);` after getting the instance?

Comment: Nice! Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: you're modifying the point in time instead of modifying the way it's displayed. Your `cal` object doesn't represent the point in time that is {13:00 in Germany, 11:00 in Greenwich} - it rather represents {11:00 in Germany, 09:00 in Greenwich}. I don't think that this was the intention.

Comment: I think this is what OP wanted

Comment: @JigarJoshi, Hi, do you know how to convert UTC time to GMT time ?

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Using `java.time`, the modern date-time API, there are many ways to do it:

1. Parse to `LocalDateTime` ➡️ Combine it with your timezone to get `ZonedDateTime` ➡️ Convert to `Instant` ➡️ Convert to `ZonedDateTime` using [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and UTC timezone.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2011-07-18 13:00:00";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant();

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 2011-07-18 11:00:00
    }
}
```

2. Parse to `LocalDateTime` ➡️ Combine it with your timezone to get `ZonedDateTime` ➡️ Convert to `Instant` ➡️ Convert to `ZonedDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#ofInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) and UTC timezone.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2011-07-18 13:00:00";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant();

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 2011-07-18 11:00:00
    }
}
```

3. **Using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2011-07-18 13:00:00";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        ZonedDateTime zdtPak = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtPak.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 2011-07-18 11:00:00
    }
}
```

4. **Using [`DateTimeFormatter#withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2011-07-18 13:00:00";

        // Using ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                        .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtPak = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtPak.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtfOutput)); // 2011-07-18 11:00:00
    }
}
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>