# How to get standard format date in android

Tags: android, sql, date, android-date

if i try the below code for eg:

i will set the date as Fri July 25 2014 10:00 AM. which gives date in milliseconds as   `1402080056000`,

now if i try to read the same milliseconds to date as below

```
  long time = 1402080056000;

  Date mydate = new Date(time);
```

mydate variable shows date as `Sat Jun 25 00:10:56 IST 2014`

```
  String DateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(time));
```

with the above statement in DateTimeString i get date as `Jun 25 , 2014 12:10:56 AM`

How to read the datetime present in `1402080056000 to  Fri July 25 2014 10:00 AM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to work on the format string,

```
String dateTimeString= 
String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm").format(new Date(time)));
```

Explicitly set time zone:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String result = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(millis));
```

Also, this would be useful [Regarding Timezones and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Comment: if i pass 0 as time, i will get date as 01-01-1970 05:30. Why not its giving GMT format time. i.e it should give me 01-01-1970 00:00

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
private String convertMilliToDate(long timestamp) {

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR DATE FORMAT");

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in
        // milliseconds to date.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, if i pass timestamp as 0, i get datetime as 01:01:70:05:30:00. But why i'm getting 5.30 AM, it should be 00 right?

Comment: if you will give wrong data to convert then by default it will convert to this date like 1-1-1970. Because timestamp calculations starts from that date. So you must need to give valid timestamp to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String date= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Date(date_in_milis)).toString();
```

Comment: Hi, i need date in GMT format, but why i get as 5.30 IST,

Comment: @Naruto .. use this.. you will get in GMT :)

Comment: Thank u, but i'm getting error, The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date) :(

Comment: @Naruto  .. try now... i have edited... just put your miliseconds in place of date_in_milis... and tell me

Comment: i tried, still i'm getting error as The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)

Comment: long DateinMilis = 0132456789;
.....String installedDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Date(DateinMilis )).toString(); ............. Its working for me bro... Just put the long date (miliseconds) and get date as String..

Comment: nope dude, i tried still i'm getting the error in the commented string. here is what i tried String installedDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Date(timestamp)).toString();. i get error as "The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)"

Comment: ha ha nomi, true. anyway i found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730797/convert-gmt-datetime-string, thanks for help nomi

Comment: Nomi, one more question. Do you know Google tasks uses which date formate is it GMT?

Comment: I am glad u r happy ;-)

Comment: Mmmm... never looked for it buddy.. no idea :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing.. keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Date-time work is easier using the Joda-Time library, which works on Android.

```
long millis = 1402080056000L;

DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( millis, timeZoneIndia );

DateTime dateTimeFrance = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );

DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

To parse a string as a date-time, search StackOverflow for "Joda parse" to find many examples.